# What is filmmask?

Tags: pcb

I am using the Allegro software to layout a board. When working with padstacks, I have four kinds of layers available:

1. Etch
2. Soldermask
3. Pastemask
4. Filmmask

I know what the first three are. What is filmmask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the film mask has no precise predefined usage but instead is an additional mask reserved for additional application specific requirements. Examples might be applying coatings to only certain pads to preserve gold or to applying glue to heavy components that require additional support.

Comment: That sounds likely.

Answer (score 1):

Filmmask would be the same thing as "silkscreen" — the human-readable markings that are printed on the board for reference designators, component outlines, part and revision numbers, etc.

Comment: Silkscreen has its own layer.